# Necessary to file US Federal W4 in addition to state W4?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, withholding, form-w-4

I already filed a state W4* with my employer - do I need to also *additionally* file a US Federal W4 with the same employer? Or does state W4 take into account for Federal W4 withholding amount also?

This is the inverse/opposite direction of the [other Question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/105645/federal-and-state-w4-forms) (asking if state W4 must be filed *after* already filing Federal W4), and therefore not exactly the same as that other Question.  That Question already covers that it is important to file state W4 *in general* (for states that have state income tax), but does not answer if state W4 should be filed *instead* of Federal W4; it also doesn't cover if Federal W4 should be filed *in addition* to an already-filed state W4 - which is what I am asking here.

*In my case, I filed an Oregon W4 for tax year 2020, filed in 2020.  But I'm not aware of anything that makes this topic specific to particular states (beyond just states that have a state income tax rather than none).

Comment: Can you clarify in the question description: was this a 2020 Oregon OR-W-4 form filled out after Jan 1, 2020?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I haven't learned why maybe that is important, but I edited in the clarification.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, given the Answer here by mhoran_psprep, I see now that maybe the importance is per before/after year 2019 in particular (rather than the particular state aspect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [item from the IRS regarding W-4 forms](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/faqs-on-the-2020-form-w-4):

This is from the section for employers:

> 17. How do I treat new employees first paid after 2019 who do not furnish a Form W-4?
>
> New employees first paid after 2019 who fail to furnish a Form W-4
> will be treated as a single filer with no other adjustments. This
> means that a single filer's standard deduction with no other entries
> will be taken into account in determining withholding. This treatment
> also generally applies to employees who previously worked for you who
> were rehired in 2020 and did not furnish a new Form W-4.

So if you need to use anything other than single with no other adjustments, then you need to submit a federal W-4. Note that even if you are married, or you plan on itemizing, or you have multiple jobs all that will be ignored. You will be taxed as a single. Now that may mean that too much will be withheld, and you will get the excess back when you file, but in that case you will be giving a free loan to the government.

If you don't submit a federal W-4 the employer is to treat you as single with no other adjustments. If you need something else you have to submit a federal form. The numbers on the state form or the federal form don't automatically flow from one to the other.

Comment: Thanks.  If I understand this info correctly, I think it is implying that (for *Federal* income tax withholding) I will be treated as single/no-adjustments *regardless* of how I may fill/submit my state W4 (including if I even don't submit a state W4 at all).  So I guess the answer to my question isn't always just yes/no, but depends on the filer's  situation (i.e: including status, adjustments..) -  and the answer about Federal is independent of state to begin with too (so, 'no', state W4 does not take into account for Federal W4 withholding amount also).